# log processing/entry deletion, multi-pipe (grep sed grep), log traversed twice. can this solution be improved?

Tags: linux, awk, sed, grep, regular-expression

Is there a cleaner way? A single pass of the large input.txt file would be preferred. Solution so far:

```
grep -e "\[.*fred" input.txt |sed 's/.*\[\([^]]*\)\].*/\1/g' |grep -vf /dev/stdin input.txt
```

Explanation:

```
grep -e "\[.*fred" input.txt |
```

Find the lines tagged with "fred" that have a left square bracket before "fred" in the line. send to

```
sed 's/.*\[\([^]]*\)\].*/\1/g' |
```

Find the IDs between the square brackets identifying all "fred" entries in the file. The number of the same ID entries per "fred" tag is not fixed, the example shows 2 lines per "fred" but it could be any number. send to

```
grep -vf /dev/stdin input.txt
```

remove all lines with these IDs from the file. (replace /dev/stdin with '-' i.e. piped input, as you require)

**input.txt:**

```
Jan  2 10:45:01 TecMint CRON[3383]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (fred)
Jan  2 10:45:01 TecMint CRON[3383]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Jan  2 10:51:34 TecMint sudo:  tecmint : TTY=unknown ; PWD=/home/tecmint ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/lib/linuxmint/mintUpdate/checkAPT.py
Jan  2 10:51:34 TecMint sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (fred)
Jan  2 10:51:39 TecMint sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Jan  2 10:55:01 TecMint CRON[4099]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (fred)
Jan  2 10:55:01 TecMint CRON[4099]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Jan  2 11:05:01 TecMint CRON[4138]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (fred)
Jan  2 11:05:01 TecMint CRON[4138]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Jan  2 11:09:01 TecMint CRON[4146]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (fred)
Jan  2 11:05:01 TecMint CRON[4199]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (bill)
Jan  2 11:05:01 TecMint CRON[4199]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
```

**Desired output:**

```
Jan  2 10:51:34 TecMint sudo:  tecmint : TTY=unknown ; PWD=/home/tecmint ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/lib/linuxmint/mintUpdate/checkAPT.py
Jan  2 10:51:34 TecMint sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (fred)
Jan  2 10:51:39 TecMint sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Jan  2 11:05:01 TecMint CRON[4199]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (bill)
Jan  2 11:05:01 TecMint CRON[4199]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that if you want to delete *anywhere in the file* lines that match IDs extracted from anywhere in the file, then there is no way to do it in a single pass.

However if you only need to delete lines going forward from the most recent match, then you could do something like:

```
$ perl -lne '$pid = $1 if /(\[.*?\]).*fred/; print unless index($_,$pid) > -1' input.txt 
Jan  2 10:51:34 TecMint sudo:  tecmint : TTY=unknown ; PWD=/home/tecmint ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/lib/linuxmint/mintUpdate/checkAPT.py
Jan  2 10:51:34 TecMint sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (fred)
Jan  2 10:51:39 TecMint sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Jan  2 11:05:01 TecMint CRON[4199]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (bill)
Jan  2 11:05:01 TecMint CRON[4199]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
```

Comment: thanks, I see your point. it is the latter, similar to most log file entry generation, 'everything' increments going forward/down the file. i'm even less knowledgeable of perl than grep/sed/awk. an elegant solution to be sure and one to fall back on. i've read suggestions that performance might be an issue if processing large files with perl compared with grep/sed/awk.